# How to check if a interface reference is a specific class

Tags: c#, interface

I was wondering if there is a way to find if my interface reference is a specific class.

For example i have DeviceInterface reference, and Playstation, PC and Mac all implement it. Is there a way to see if DeviceInterface is a PC?

I have thought about using a enum to define the type and using that, but is there a way of avoiding this and using a type check or something along those lines?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how about `if ( obj is Mac)` ?

Comment: Note, that if you have to make checks like this often, it's a sign that you might want to re-think the architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you have

```
DeviceInterface PcDevice = new PC();
```

In that case you can just do:

```
if (PcDevice is PC) { console.WriteLine("I'm a PC"); }
```

read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) to understand the *is* and *as* operators better